# Storing ISO 8601 duration in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, setinterval, intervals, duration, iso8601

Need to store duration in ISO 8601 format `P[n]Y[n]M[n]DT[n]H[n]M[n]S` in PostgreSQL, then retrieve it in a script in the same format. In what data type to store ISO 8601 duration in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Googling shows that some people store ISO 8601 duration as `VARCHAR`. PostgreSQL though among other [date/time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) has an [`interval` data type](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-interval/) which can store and return duration in `iso_8601` format. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE xyz(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  duration INTERVAL
);
```

Duration in ISO 8601 format

```
# SELECT duration FROM xyz;
 duration
----------
 PT0S
 PT1M28S
(2 rows)
```

The output style of `interval` can be set by `SET intervalstyle` command

```
SET intervalstyle = 'iso_8601';
```